# Inserting efficiency between set and unordered set?

Tags: c++, performance

What are the efficiency differences between inserting thousands of random elements into a set and into an unordered set? How can I measure them?

Comment: To "measure" them, you could measure the time or clock ticks. (Don't forget to make this in release mode with optimization.) Another hint is given in doc.: [`std::set::insert()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert): _Logarithmic in the size of the container, O(log(size()))._ vs. [`std::unordered_set::insert()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/insert): _Average case: O(1), worst case O(size())_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to measure something have a look at a [profiler](http://www.valgrind.org/) or simply measure the runtime.

For their complexity have a look at the documentation under the point "complexity". [set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert) [unordered_set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/insert).

Copy from set documentation:

> Complexity
>
> 1-2) Logarithmic in the size of the container, O(log(size())).
>
> 3-4) Amortized constant if the insertion happens in the position just after the hint, logarithmic in the size of the container otherwise.
>   (until C++11)
>
> 3-4) Amortized constant if the insertion happens in the position just before the hint, logarithmic in the size of the container otherwise.
>   (since C++11)
>
> 5-6) O(N*log(size() + N)), where N is the number of elements to insert.
>
> 7) Logarithmic in the size of the container, O(log(size())).
>
> 8) Amortized constant if the insertion happens in the position just before the hint, logarithmic in the size of the container otherwise.

Copy from unordered_set documentation

> Complexity
>
> 1-4) Average case: O(1), worst case O(size())
>
> 5-6) Average case: O(N), where N is the number of elements to insert. Worse case: O(N*size()+N)
>
> 7-8) Average case: O(1), worst case O(size())